# Sample space of the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov $D$ statistic?

Tags: r, self-study, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am trying to write a simple piece of code to produce the sample space for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic $D_{m,n} = \underset{x}{\max}\left|S_{m}(x)-S_{n}(x)\right|$, where $m$ and $n$ are the sample sizes, and $S_{m}(x)$ and $S_{n}(x)$ the two empirical distribution functions of the two samples. In plain language, $D_{m,n}$ is the absolute value of the largest difference between the two empirical distribution functions at points $x$ (Gibbons & Chakraborti, 2010).

My thinking is that the possible values of $D_{m,n}$ range from $\min\left(\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{n}\right)$ at the lower bound (because at the very least the difference between $S_{m}(x)$ and $S_{n}(x)$ at the smallest value of $x$ will be either $\frac{1}{m}$ or $\frac{1}{n}$), and $1$ at the upper bound (because it is possible one empirical distribution function reaches its maximum while the other is still at its minimum).

Intermediate values are all the differences in the set comprising $\min\left(\left|\frac{i}{m}-\frac{j}{n}\right|,\min\left(\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$ for $i=1,2,\dots,m$ and $j=1,2,\dots,n$.

Here is my R code:

```
KSSS <- function(m, n) {
  # start with steps based on the inverse of each sample size
  values <- sort(unique(c((1:m)/m, (1:n)/n)))
  nv <- length(values)
  additional.values <- c()  # list the magnitude of differences in values
  for (i in 1:(nv-1) ) {
    for (j in (i+1):nv) {
      additional.values <- c(additional.values, abs(values[i]-values[j]))
      }
    }
  if (length(additional.values[additional.values >= min(1/m,1/n)]) == 0) {
    # If no additional.values are greater than the smallest possible 
    # value of D, return values
    return(values)
    }
   else{
    # Include any additional.values greater than the smallest 
    # possible value of D
    values <- sort(c(additional.values, values))
    values <- values[values >= min(1/nx,1/ny)]
    return(values[!duplicated(round(values,12))])
    }
  }
```

**My questions:**

1. Is my reasoning about the set of possible values of $D_{m,n}$ correct?
2. Does my code accomplish this? (General improvements to the algorithm welcome :).

**References**:
Gibbons, J. D. and Chakraborti, S. (2010). *Nonparametric Statistical Inference*. Chapman & Hall/CRC, 5th edition edition.

Comment: It is possible for $D_{m,n}$ to be zero: this will happen for two identical datasets (up to permutation).  Since $S_m \in \{0, 1/m, 2/m, \ldots, 1\}$ and $S_n\in\{0,1/n,2/n, \ldots, 1\},$ wouldn't it be enough to say that the sample space is a subset of the set of their absolute differences? That could be generated (in ascending order) in `R` with a single line, `function(m,n) sort(unique(c(outer(0:m, 0:n, function(i,j) abs(i*n-j*m))))) / (m*n)`  Indeed, by leaving off the final `/(m*n)` you will generate the numerators of all the fractions, producing exact results.

Comment: Thank you, whuber (for both insights)! I would be *delighted* to accept that as an answer. :)

Comment: Hmm... I was really just feeling you out for clarification of your question :-).

Comment: @whuber too bad you are such a natural with the bullseye answers. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for $D_{m,n}$ to be zero: this will happen when the K-S test is applied to two identical datasets (up to permutation).

Since $S_m \in \{0, 1/m, 2/m, \ldots, 1\}$ and $S_n\in\{0,1/n,2/n, \ldots, 1\},$ wouldn't it be enough to say that the sample space is a subset of the set of their absolute differences? A function to do this could be written in `R` with a single line,

```
function(m,n) unique(c(outer(0:m, 0:n, function(i,j) abs(i*n-j*m)))) / (m*n)
```

`outer` generates all ordered pairs $(i,j)$ in $\{0,1,\ldots, m\}\times \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ and for each one computes $|in-jm|.$  `c` flattens this from a matrix to an array and `unique` converts that to the set of its elements (in some arbitrary order).  The final division by `/(m*n)` yields all the the distinct values

$$\frac{|in-jm|}{mn}= \left| \frac{i}{m} - \frac{j}{n} \right|.$$

You could sort these (using `sort`) if you like.  Remove the $0$ when $m\ne n,$ too, if that helps.  By leaving off the final `/(m*n)` you will generate the numerators of all the fractions, producing exact results (at least when $mn$ doesn't overflow the long integer storage mode in `R`) if that's desired.

Comment: Just noticed that if $m=n$, then the result should just be `c(0:m)/m`.

Comment: Been playing around with this and I think your solution defines the K-S sample space allowing for ties (in the sense of [my recent combinatoric question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/598571/44269) which you helped me with). For example, when $m=3$ and $n=4$, your function gives $0.08\bar{3}$ (i.e. one twelfth) as a possible value (corresponding to the absolute difference between $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ (or between $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$). However, when no ties are possible, it is not possible for $0.08\bar{3}$ to be the **largest** absolute difference between both eCDFs.