# How can I evaluate the performance of a program to calculate the exact Kolmogorov-Smirnof PDF

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

For reasons abstruse I wish to create a program to calculate the exact density function for the $D$ statistic from Kolmogorov-Smirnov's two-sample test. Here is the code I have so far.

```
dDx <- function(d, nx, ny) {

  # KS.D: Takes an ordering vector which represents the sorting of two samples
  # as 0s and 1s, and returns the Kolmogorov-Smirnov D statistic.
  KS.D <- function(sample) {
    nx <- length(sample[sample==1])
    ny <- length(sample[sample==0])
    D <- 0
    for (i in 1:(nx + ny)) {
      D <- max(D, abs( length(sample[1:i][sample[1:i] == 1])/nx - length(sample[1:i][sample[1:i] == 0])/ny) )
      }
    return(D) 
    }

  # n2Ck: takes two scalars n >= k, and returns an n choose k by n matrix,
  #       where each row identifies a unique size k combination of n
  #       variables. The resulting matrix includes all possible combinations. 
  n2Ck <- function(n,k) {
    m <- choose(n,k)             # number of n2Ck(n,k) combinations
    out <- matrix(0,m,n)
    ones <- combn(n,k)       
    for (i in 1:m) {
      out[i,][ones[,i]] <-1
      }
    return(out)
    }
  precision <- 12
  out <- d
  m <- choose(nx+ny,nx)             # number of n2Ck(nx+ny,nx) combinations
  combinations <- n2Ck(nx+ny,nx)  # possible combinations of (routes through) nx+ny samples
  index <- 0
  for (val in d) {          # d loop is for each supplied d value
   index <- index + 1
   count <- 0
   for (i in 1:m) {         # i loop counts the number of times d occurs out of all possible combinations
     D <- KS.D(combinations[i,]) 
     # The below conditional is sensitive to precision!
     if (round(D,digits=precision) == round(val,digits=precision)) {
       count <- count + 1
       }
     }
   out[index] <- count/m
   }
 return(out) 
 }
```

How can I evaluate how accurate my code is? (I.e. that it produces numerically correct results?)

I can certainly feed it the sample space of $D$ for given parameters `nx` and `ny` (thanks to [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/353813/44269)).

**But how can I evaluate the accuracy of the program's output?** Are there tables of published value I can compare against?

PS: It's 100% true that I am not a CS type, and there probably a zillion ways to improve my code aside from the accuracy question: such feedback most welcome as comments.

Comment: It's probably worth explicitly mentioning (either in the title, the opening paragraph, or both) that you're dealing with the two sample test; typically if not explicitly qualified people will tend to assume you mean the one-sample test. There are exact small sample tables in a few places; indeed these can be generated fairly directly.

Comment: Here's code to check the pmf  for any specific instance:  `f=function(x,m,n) ks.test(head(x,m),tail(x,n))$statistic; sdf=function(y,x) setdiff(x,y); m=3;n=4;x=combn(m+n,m);xy=rbind(x,apply(x,2,sdf,x=1:(m+n)));table(apply(xy,2,f,m=m,n=n))`

Comment: You'll probably want to put that on separate lines, in which case replace the `;` with returns (i.e. the "Enter" key)

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Thank you! I see that your code produces elements of the sample space for this test, but I am struggling to find the probability density output? For example, my `dDx(.25,3,4)` gives `0.02857143`, and `dDx` sums to 1 across the whole sample space... is that accurate?

Comment: The output table consists of a set of labels -- the sample space -- and a set of counts (unnormalized pmf, sorry to be unclear). Divide those counts by their sum to get the normalized pmf. If you assign the last line to `a`, then `a/sum(a)` generates the normalized probabilities, the first of which is `0.02857143`, the second is `0.08571429` and so on

Comment: @ close votes: The question is not about coding, it asks how to evaluate the performance of *a* program that is supposed to calculate this density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tables in Conover's *Practical Nonparametric Statistics*, 3E, tables A19 and A20.

You can also calculate values as follows:

```
f=function(x,m,n) ks.test(head(x,m),tail(x,n))$statistic 
sdf=function(y,x) setdiff(x,y) 
m=3
n=4
x=combn(m+n,m)
xy=rbind(x,apply(x,2,sdf,x=1:(m+n)))
a=table(apply(xy,2,f,m=m,n=n))
a/sum(a)
```

The output for this case is:

```
         0.25 0.333333333333333 0.416666666666667               0.5 0.666666666666667              0.75                 1 
   0.02857143        0.08571429        0.22857143        0.25714286        0.17142857        0.17142857        0.05714286
```

Just replace $m$ and $n$ as needed.

If $m$ and $n$ are not small this will be slower than it might be. It is possible to speed it up (e.g. the function `f` does unnecessary calculation that could be avoided by making the relevant call to get the statistic that can be found in the code for `ks.test`). Indeed there's a bunch of ways to make it faster, but it might still be useful enough to check cases.